# How to read Outlook folder with a LINQ query?

Tags: linq, email, outlook, directory, mapi

I need help or sample code in VB.NET to read a specified outlook folder that is not the inbox or a subfolder of inbox

Say folder name is "foo", how can I rerieve emails with a LINQ query, possibly adding where clause(s) for the from, to, date, subject or body content.

Thanks :-)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: at least put vb.net tag plus linq is for querying data from collection, so first you need to get whatever collection you need to read then query what you wnat. so i guess this have nothing to do with linq

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail :-)
Why does it need to be LINQ? It might look neat in you source code, but it can bring your application down to its knees - if you need any kind of restriction, use the native methods whenever you can. In your case, that would be `Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict`.
If you need to access an arbitrary folder, use the `Namespace.Folders` collection – it contains top level folders from all stores.
If the folder is on the same level as the Inbox, use `Inbox.Parent.Folders` collection.

Comment: I understand, I woukd have thought that MS wsupplied an Outlook LINQ provider that would not add too much of an overhead.
That being said, a small working sample would save me lots of time :-)

Comment: MS will not add a LINQ provider, you can bet on it - Outlook, just like all other Office apps, is a native app accessible to all languages, not just.Net. What is your restriction? Pleasde be more specific. As for the Outlook related  question, post them at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/outlookdev/threads

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/scipbe.common.office/

Add it to your project and you can use linq like syntax with outlook.

Also

http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/linqqer-exposing-linq-extensions-on-non-ienumerableiqueriable-collections/